# Can you SET a MySQL variable in ADOdb to avoid repeating bind variables?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I'm using ADOdb with MySQL in PHP and trying to pass a keyword multiple times as a bind variable without having to repeat it in my $queryParams array, is this possible? I'm having an error thrown due to the semicolon.

```php
  $queryParams = [$keyword, $row_ids];
  $query = "
    SET @myKeyword = ?;
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE row_id IN (?)
    AND (
      row_desc1 = @myKeyword
      OR row_des2 = @myKeyword
      OR row_desc3 = @myKeyword
    )";

  $connection->execute($query, $queryParams);
```

What I'm trying to avoid:

```php
  $queryParams = [$row_ids, $keyword, $keyword, $keyword];
  $query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE row_id IN (?)
    AND (
      row_desc1 = ?
      OR row_des2 = ?
      OR row_desc3 = ?
    )";

  $connection->execute($query, $queryParams);
```

Comment: ...why are you using ADODB in PHP instead of PDO?

Comment: Because that's what the codebase I was assigned to is using and I have a job to do.

Comment: You have my sympathy.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot parameterize the `WHERE x IN ( ... )` operator in SQL. You need to either generate dynamic parameters (which is almost as fun..er...painful as Dynamic-SQL) or do an `INNER JOIN` on a table-valued-parameter.

Comment: And then your next question will be how to bind multiple values for in operator as the query matches the first value only...

Comment: @Dai you can, just not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most query interfaces do not support multi-statements by default. That is, you can't send two SQL statements in one call.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/multi-statement.html says:

> The client must announce that it wants multi-statements by either setting the CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS capability or by using COM_SET_OPTION.

This is something the code making the connection (ADODB in this case) would have to do when you connect.

But it won't work anyway, because multi-statements cannot work with `prepare()`, therefore cannot be used with query parameters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html says:

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

You could make two calls, one to do the `SET` and the second to do the `SELECT` that uses that variable you had set in the first call. As long as the two calls use the same MySQL session, the variable will keep its value.

Alternatively, in your example of repeating the keyword, you could write it this way:

```
AND (
  ? IN (row_desc1, row_des2, row_desc3)
)
```

This allows you to pass the keyword parameter once, and it still compares it to three columns.

P.S.: You also have a problem with your other condition: `row_id IN (?)`. You can't use a single parameter for multiple values for an IN predicate like that.

Comment: _"Most query interfaces do not support multi-query by default. That is, you can't send two SQL statements in one call."_ - is that something unique to PHP? Because ODBC/OLE-DB/ADO.NET supports statement-batches, heck, even MS Access 97 does....

Comment: It's not unique to PHP, it's a MySQL connector option that is not enabled by default. Also I forgot another issue: Even if the ADODB connector allows you to enable multi-statements, MySQL does not support `prepare()` for multi-statements, so you can't use multi-statements and query parameters anyway.

Comment: It's a CSV list of numbers, e.g. `WHERE row_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);`

Comment: Right, I assumed that it was a CSV string. But it will execute as if you had written a query with `WHERE row_id IN ('1, 2, 3, 4')` which is a single string, not a list of discrete values. Keep in mind that query parameters are not simply string substitution.